# Is \listfiles guaranteed to be identical for the same preamble given an up-to-date distribution?

Tags: distributions, logging

LaTeX provides `\listfiles`, which for a particular source file provides:

```
scrreprt.cls    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script document class (report)
scrkbase.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script package (type area)
chngcntr.sty    2009/09/02 v1.0a change counter resetting
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
...
```

Will the lines between `*File List*` and `***********` be **identical**, regardless of source file (after preamble), distribution, and operating system, provided every package/class is up-to-date? If no, what will be different?

I am distributing a `cls` file and want to provide a script that parses the log file, to ensure users are using up-to-date packages. I know I can write a regex like:

```
^\\s*([a-z]+\\.(?:(?:cls)|(?:sty)))    ([12][0-9]{3}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}) (v?\\s?(?:er)?[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9a-z]+)?)?.*$
```

but I wonder whether I can just verify the raw lines (containing `.sty` and `.cls` files).

<sub>(If my regex is wrong, feel free to let me know too :-).)</sub>

Comment: No, they won't be same in general because there are users that keep (older) copies of `.sty` files in their TEXINPUT path other than the distribution directories, so there might be a mismatch in the versions

Comment: I'd consider such a set-up 'non-identical'. That is, if the `\listfiles` differ in that respect, then I would be happy for it to be flagged as different.